# how to pass uint32[], uint8[] parameter to smart contract in web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, ethereumjs, arrays

I'm doing estimateGas.
here's my code.

```
var sdate = new Date('2021-07-01 00:00:00');
var edate = new Date('2021-07-31 00:00:00');
var arrDate = [];
arrDate.push(sdate/1000);
arrDate.push(edate/1000);

var arrCategory = [1,12,14];

var param1 = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('uint32[]',arrDate);
var param2 = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('uint8[]',arrCategory);

let Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(myPack.abi, myPack.ca);
Contract.methods.createTicket(param1, param2).estimateGas({from: accounts[0]})
  .then(console.log);
```

and I met error

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.map is not a function
    at h.formatParam (index.js:218)
    at index.js:100
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at h.encodeParameters (index.js:94)
    at index.js:439
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.d._encodeMethodABI (index.js:438)
    at Object.d._processExecuteArguments (index.js:701)
    at Object.d._executeMethod (index.js:720)
    at estimateGas (issuecfm:257)
```

I tried something before encodeParameter

BigNumber

```
var BN =  web3.utils.BN;
arrDate = arrDate.map(item => {return new BN(item)});
arrCategory = arrCategory.map(item => {return new BN(item)});
```

and String

```
arrDate = arrDate.map(item => {return item.toString()});
arrCategory = arrCategory.map(item => {return item.toString()});
```

After a lot of searching, I tried what I could. but I still get the same error.
I would really appreciate it if you could teach me how to modify my code.

---

---

added

I modified my code like this.

```
var parameters = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['uint32[]', 'uint8[]'],[arrDate, arrCategory]);
 console.log(parameters);
 console.log(web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(['uint32[]', 'uint8[]'],parameters));

 let Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(myPack.abi, myPack.ca);
 Contract.methods.createTicket(parameters).estimateGas({from: accounts[0]})
 .then(console.log);


0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060e31e7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000615b16ef0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060e31e7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000615b16ef000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000090000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
c {0: Array(4), 1: Array(3), __length__: 2}
```

I checked that the values ​​of parameters are encoded and decoded correctly in the console. &-I

and met next error

```
errors.js:33 Uncaught Error: Invalid number of parameters for "createTicket". Got 1 expected 2!
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfParams (errors.js:33)
    at Object.d._createTxObject (index.js:670)
    at estimateGas (issuecfm:261)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (issuecfm:130)
    at j (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to encode both parameters in an array using the `web.eth.abi.encodeParameters()` [function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#id7):

You pass in an array of types and an array with the values of the parameters like this:

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['uint32[]','uint8[]'], [arrDate, arrCategory]);
```

---

Inside your solidity contract you decode the data like so:

```
function createTicket(bytes calldata params) external ... {
    (uint32[] arrDate, uint8[] arrCategory) = abi.decode(params, (uint32[], uint8[]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried running it, but met another problem.

Comment: and I added my modified code and error.

Comment: added more explanation

Comment: I got a simple solution. there's no need to encode parameters. thank you for your kind answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got a simple solution from stack overflow.

> Using the web3 contract helper function, you need to pass the "raw" JS
> params, not the ABI-encoded data.

so I modified my code

```
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(myPack.abi, myPack.ca);

// mind the `arrDate` and `arrCategory` instead of `param1` and `param2`
contract.methods.createTicket(arrDate, arrCategory)
    .estimateGas({from: accounts[0]})
    .then(console.log);
```

It works!!